# executeSqlScript fails with Spring for PL/SQL block

Tags: sql, spring, oracle11g, spring-test

Im trying to populate my database using the builtin function `executeSqlScript` from `AbstractTransactionalJUnit4SpringContextTests` using the following external SQL file.

```
declare
   id number;
begin
   insert into table1 (field1) values ('V1') returning account__id  into id;
   insert into table2 (my_id, field2) VALUES (id, 'Value3');
end;
```

However im getting the following error. Im not sure what im allowed to do in a SQL file I would like to execute using `executeSqlScript`.

```
org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.ScriptStatementFailedException: Failed to execute SQL script statement at line 1 of resource class path resource [testdata.sql]: declare id number; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: ORA-06550: line 1, column 17:
PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "end-of-file" when expecting one of the following:

   := . ( @ % ; not null range default character
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: ORA-06550: line 1, column 17:
PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "end-of-file" when expecting one of the following:

   := . ( @ % ; not null range default character
```

So my questions are:
What am I allowed to express in the SQL file for `executeSqlScript`?
What is the cause of the error im reciving?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It appears that you are attempting to use features of PL/SQL in your script.

The `executeSqlScript(..)` methods in `AbstractTransactionalJUnit4SpringContextTests` internally delegate to `ScriptUtils.executeSqlScript(..)` behind the scenes, and `ScriptUtils` only supports pure SQL scripts.

So you'll likely need to switch to simple SQL statements and find a different mechanism for retrieving the value of the `account__id` from `table1`.

Another option (which I have **not** tried) would be to change the statement separator to something other than `";"` (e.g., `"end;"`), but you cannot do that via `AbstractTransactionalJUnit4SpringContextTests.executeSqlScript`. Instead, you'd need to invoke `ScriptUtils.executeSqlScript(..)` or (perhaps preferably) use a `ResourceDatabasePopulator`.